# Reverting to old commit in remote without keeping track of local commits

Tags: git

I found the instructions to revert to old commits in remote [here](https://kb.swarthmore.edu:8443/display/ITSDOCS/Roll+back+git+remote+to+a+previous+commit).

These are the steps:

> 1.) Find the id (SHA hash) of the last good commit, this is the commit you want to become HEAD
>
> 2.) In your local repo fetch that commit with the follow command
>    git fetch origin :refs/remotes/origin/
>
> 3.) If you have local commits that have not been pushed, create a local branch to preserve them:
>   git branch -b
>
> 4.) Go back to the original branch
>   git checkout
>
> 5.) Reset the branch to the good commit found in step 1:
>   git reset --hard
>
> 6.) Push your reset repo to the remote (will need to force the update):
>    git push -f origin
>
> 7.) Merge in your commits that you stashed in a branch in step 3:
>    git merge

My question is, if I want to skip step 3, I should also skip step 4 and 7 right? Then I will just lose local changes that I committed locally. Right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, if you do not have any work to save then you do not need to create the separate branch in Step 3.

This would make Step 4 not relevant since you are already on the original branch.

Step 7 is also not relevant because there are no outstanding commits to merge in.

Also worthy of noting, is that if you did have some outstanding commits, you won't "lose" them by skipping Step 3. If for some reason you did need to get them back you can retrieve them from Git's [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).